# Read a tuple from a file and convert it to a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, file, tuples

I want to read a tuple from a file and convert it to a list.

The file has this: `(1,2,3)`

My code:

```py
with open('scores.txt','r+') as scores:
    score_file=list(scores.read())
    print(score_file)
```

The output is: `['(', '1', ',', '2', ',', '3', ')']` but I want that: `[1,2,3]`
How can I do this:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the `scores.read()` returns the object of type `str`, with `list(scores.read())`, the `str` object is broken into the `list` with individual characters.

You could use `ast.literal_eval()` to convert to the right datatype and then convert to list as:

```
import ast
with open('scores.txt','r+') as scores:
    score_file = scores.read()
    score_file = list(ast.literal_eval(score_file))
    
    print(score_file)
    print(type(score_file))
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3]
<class 'list'>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do

```
lst = []

with open('scores.txt','r+') as scores:
    score_file = scores.read()
    for item in score_file:
        if item != '(' and item != ')' and item != ',':
            lst.append(int(item))

print(lst)
```

which iterates through the scores and adds them as integers to a list.

Comment: I have this error message:
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Local-Admin\Documents\_git\test.py", line 6, in <module>
    lst.append(int(score))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '('`

Comment: @NicholasKrebs Sorry, just edited my answer to account for the non-integer items in the list.

Comment: thanks but now the problem is if the number is like 11, it writes `(1,1)` when the script runs twice

Comment: @NicholasKrebs Sorry, without the data you are using it's hard to test my code. In that case you are better off using one of the other answers as they are better than my method anyway.

Comment: yes i know i only wanted you to know with a number with more than one digit its not possible. and i only use numbers

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer not to import modules you could use list comprehension. For each score in scores you strip the parentheses and split on the comma. Then cast to int.

```
with open('scores.txt','r+') as scores:
    for score in scores:
        print([int(i) for i in score.strip('()').split(',')])

>>> [1, 2, 3]
```